# Wapiti Security tool: Getting "Invalid Syntax Error "

Tags: python, python-2.7, security, wapiti

I followed the following steps:

1. Install Python27 and also download `wapiti`, placed it inside `c:\wapiti-2.2.1` .
2. Set environment variable for python(var name : `c:\python27`).
3. Open python command prompt.
4. Change root directory
   for step 4 i have used script:

   ```
   import os
   os.chdir("c:\wapiti-2.2.1\src")
   ```

After doing all this ,still i am getting error while for

```
python wapiti.py -h
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I face the same problem. However I've tried with an older machine running python 2.5.1 and wapiti works fine. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Think your missing a \ in your path:

```
import os 
os.chdir("c:\wapiti-2.2.1\src")
```